# Sharepoint 2010 web application zones and AAM configuration

Tags: security, administration, configuration, web-application-zones

Is it possible in Sharepoint 2010 to achieve the following goal:

1. On single Web Application add two urls (through AAM), one is usual http://site.com and another is SSL-enabled https://my.site.com and configure anonymous access for the first url only?

I am investigating this task and currently looking on AAM/zones configuration. Is that correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that's possible.  You will need to extend the webapplication to an additional virtual directory in IIS.  Then you should have two virtual directories in IIS for the same web application.  Then you can configure the ssl and anonymous differently.

Comment: We do the exact same thing.  We have the default app with Anon access enabled, and an extended app for HTTPS.  In addition we have web app rules that restrict user logon (except for crawl account) to the Anon enabled trunk so all editing is done via HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you guys! Jesus, have you configured all that scenario through CA or directly in IIS by creating extra site and pointing it to virtual directory created by SharePoint?

Comment: And what do you mean by "web app rules"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track. Here's a good place to start.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261698.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Administration, under Application Management open Manage web applications.

From there click your web applications and hit Extend on the Ribbon. There you can configure it with new Security settings. You can even extend it on the same port, but remember that the Header can't be the same then.

And don't forget to update your DNS Server, a CNAME or A-record.